# Trying to erase the sketch drawn on present screen while navigating to the other page

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

Hi i am trying to erase the sketch drawn on present screen automatically if navigating to next screen.
xaml code

```
public WorkBookP()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    ink.InkPresenter.InputDeviceTypes = CoreInputDeviceTypes.Mouse | CoreInputDeviceTypes.Touch;

    // Set initial ink stroke attributes.
    InkDrawingAttributes drawingAttributes = new InkDrawingAttributes();
    drawingAttributes.Color = Windows.UI.Colors.Black;
    drawingAttributes.IgnorePressure = false;
    drawingAttributes.FitToCurve = true;
    ink.InkPresenter.UpdateDefaultDrawingAttributes(drawingAttributes);
}
```

On this Nextbtntap click i want the text drawn on present screen should removed automatically

```
private void Nextbtntap(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)  
{              
    ink.InkPresenter.InputProcessingConfiguration.Mode = InkInputProcessingMode.Inking;  
    currentIndex++;  
    if (currentIndex > 9)  
    {  
        currentIndex = 9;  
        return;  
    }  
    Digitcsimg.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/Workbook/DigitArt/WS" + currentIndex + ".png"));             
    DispDigit.Text = DigCount[currentIndex];  
}
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, it seems you want to clear the `InkCanvas` when a button is tapped. If so, you can try with [InkStrokeContainer.Clear](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.input.inking.inkstrokecontainer#Windows_UI_Input_Inking_InkStrokeContainer_Clear) method.

For example, you can add the following code into `Nextbtntap` method to remove all inks in the `InkCanvas` named "ink".

```
ink.InkPresenter.StrokeContainer.Clear();
```